# How to activate Shumway in Firefox?

Tags: gnome, firefox, browser, shumway

Because Adobe Flash is so insecure I want to install Shumway as an alternative as I currently have nothing installed so am having to do with the built-in HTML5 players on the sites which have them, and most don't so I mostly can't do anything which requires something like Flash.

So I went to the Mozilla Shumway page where I went to the [section describing how to enable it](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Shumway#how_do_I_enable_it.3F) in Firefox, however after following its instructions and going to the `about:config` section of my browser I could not find anything when I searched for `shumway.disabled`.

So how do I enable/install it? I am running Firefox 43 (the current release) on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the Shumway project [**has been retired**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=Shumway) (click `show info` next to `Product: Firefox Graveyard`). So the following answer is **only** here now for historical reference purposes, **do not follow it for practical use**.

---

As it says on the page:

> Available in Nightly on Desktop for all platforms, *preff'd off* Will
>   not ride the trains for now, so not available on Aurora, Beta, and
>   Release

And the section has the title of `Current Shumway In Nightly` thus meaning that Shumway can only be enabled in this way (by going to `about:config` and then changing the option `shumway.disabled`) in the Firefox Nightly builds, this does not include the current stable release (what you are running), nor does it include Beta, or Aurora.

So in order to install it on one of these which is not the Firefox Nightly, you will have to go to the [Shumway Github page here](https://github.com/mozilla/shumway) and then go down the page until you get to the `Getting Started` section, in this section there are two sub-sections, go to the `Extension` one and [click on the link](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway/extension/firefox/shumway.xpi) to install Shumway in your browser.

**Note:** As Shumway is still under development the method of installation may change, so this answer will be updated accordingly. If there has been an update to the installation method and this answer has not been updated, please comment.